# Spring dependency injection issue

Tags: spring

I have a bean I am trying to configure in Spring context using Constructor injection. When I pass subclass for one of the constructor arguments, the bean is instantiated by Spring container only if I do not specify the "type" attribute. Would anybody have any idea what's wrong? Below are more specifics.

```
class MyClass{
   public MyClass(SomeAbstractBase absObject){
      //do stuff
   }
}

class ConcreteClass extends SomeAbstractBase{
   //
}
```

Spring configs (First and second do not work but the third one using type attribute works)-
Config I-

```
<bean id="concreteclass" 
         class="ConcreteClass"/>
<bean id="myclass" 
        class="MyClass">
        <constructor-arg type="ConcreteClass" ref="concreteclass"/>
</bean>
```

Config II-

```
<bean id="concreteclass" 
         class="ConcreteClass"/>
<bean id="myclass" 
        class="MyClass">
        <constructor-arg type="SomeAbstractBase" ref="concreteclass"/>
</bean>
```

Config III-

```
 <bean id="concreteclass" 
             class="ConcreteClass"/>
    <bean id="myclass" 
            class="MyClass">
            <constructor-arg ref="concreteclass"/>
    </bean>
```

I get the following exception at initialization-

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jedispool' defined in class path resource
>   [cache-spring-config.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor
>   (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to
>   avoid type ambiguities)

Why would neither of the first or second config work?

Thank you

Comment: For your example above, are you using static nested classes?

Answer (score 0):

Type argument accept only the full qualified type (because if not spring cannot determine exactly the package and the type will not match your class):

So you need to use the canonical name of your class to be a type

```
ConcreteClass => com.your.app.ConcreteClass
```

A class is not just a name, is a package +  name (too be short)

Comment: That would fail as well for the 3rd config.

Comment: Hum I tried on my webapp, using canonical classname in type argument works. But there is no reason to specify type when you are using ref, spring will resolv itself.

Comment: I meant it would fail in the bean declaration for `concreteclass` where OP is also specifying a class name.

Comment: Ho yeah I was too focused on the second bean that I didn't see that. You'r true :)

Comment: But you are almost correct. Assuming the classes OP is using are static nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error you had appeared because you had `static` nested classes. Here's an SSCCE

```
package test;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(MyClass.class.getName());
        System.out.println(ConcreteClass.class.getName());
        System.out.println(SomeAbstractBase.class.getName());
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");  
    }
    static class MyClass {
        public MyClass(SomeAbstractBase absObject) {
        }
    }
    static class ConcreteClass extends SomeAbstractBase {
        //
    }
    static abstract class SomeAbstractBase {
    }
}
```

With `spring.xml` containing

```
<bean id="concreteclass" class="test.Test.ConcreteClass" />
<bean id="myclass" class="test.Test.MyClass">
    <constructor-arg  type="test.Test.SomeAbstractBase" ref="concreteclass" />
</bean>
```

The above fails with a `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`. In this specific example, the `class` attribute isn't used correctly. The fully qualified class name for `ConcreteClass` is `test.Test$ConcreteClass`, not `test.Test.ConcreteClass` as I've specified. The same applies to `MyClass` and `SomeAbstractBase`.

However, specifying `test.Test.ConcreteClass` in the `class` attribute for the `concreteclass` bean doesn't fail because at some point during processing of bean declarations, Spring tries to resolve the `class` String into a `Class` object using `Class.forName(String)`. It will call [`ClassUtils.forName(String, ClassLoader)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) to do this. Initially it will fail because there is no such class `test.Test.ConcreteClass`. However, this is done in a `try-catch` which on `ClassNotFoundException` will transform the `String` class name from `test.Test.ConcreteClass` to `test.Test$ConcreteClass` and try again. It will work and correctly create a bean of type `test.Test$ConcreteClass` for your `concreteclass` bean.

When it tries to create your `myclass` bean, however, it does not apply such logic for resolving which constructor to use and therefore cannot understand that with the `type` attribute value of `test.Test.SomeAbstractBase`, you actually meant `test.Test$SomeAbstractBase`, so it fails saying the type is ambiguous.

Change your bean declarations to correct types

```
<bean id="concreteclass" class="test.Test$ConcreteClass" />
<bean id="myclass" class="test.Test$MyClass">
    <constructor-arg  type="test.Test$SomeAbstractBase" ref="concreteclass" />
</bean>
```

and it will work.

Take a look at [kakawait's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19320715/438154), you need to specify the fully qualified class name for the bean you are trying to instantiate.